# Computing norm of linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

This is the question that was given to me:
 [image: this]

I was able to prove that the operator is bounded: it is bounded by the infinity norm of $f$.

Since it is bounded, it has a finite norm, $$\|T\|= \sup\limits_{f\in C[0,1]} \frac{\|Tf\|}{\|f\|}. $$

I noticed that for $f=1$ this is equal to $1/2$. I think that I need to find an upper bound, and show that it is attained, probably with $f=1$, but I am stuck as to what this bound might be. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ denote the sup norm.  For all $x\in[0,1]$, 
$$\begin{align*}|Tf(x)|&=\left|\int_0^x (x-t)f(t)\,dt\right|\\
&\leq \int_0^x|(x-t)f(t)|\,dt\\
&\leq \int_0^x(x-t)\|f\|_\infty\,dt\\
&=\frac12 x^2\|f\|_\infty\\
&\leq \frac12\|f\|_\infty
\end{align*},$$
hence $\|Tf\|_\infty\leq \frac12\|f\|_\infty$.  This shows that $\|T\|\leq \frac12$, and your example with $f=1$ shows $\|T\|\geq \frac12$, so the norm must equal $\frac12$.

Comment: Wow I feel pretty  stupid  now, thanks!

Comment: Why is the first line of the computations just $|\cdot |$ and not $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$? Also, when you guys say $f = 1$, does this mean $f$ is the identity map?

Comment: @user11032: $|\cdot|$ is used for the absolute value of numbers, and that is what is involved on the first line.  To prove that $\|g\|_\infty\leq K$ is equivalent to proving that $|g(x)|\leq K$ for all $x$.  In this case the latter allows us to use the definition of $T$ to bound $|Tf(x)|$ in terms of $\|f\|_\infty$ as shown above.  $f=1$ means the constant function $f(x)=1$ for all $x$.  It would be the multiplicative identity if the space were endowed with pointwise multiplication, but no consideration of such multiplication occurs here.